# Having trouble with c++ integers and math

Tags: c++, console-application

So its a Friday, Ive been working this app and my head is about to explode. I can't find the problem anywhere!!! I am a beginner coder so I am hoping the gods of stackoverflow can guide me in the right direction or provide some feedback!! :]

This console app is just a simple parking time ticket. The code complies fine with no errors. But my math is all messed up!

Here is a sample result: With time entered as 3:50 and exit 5:29 with vehicle as T.

```
 TIME-IN          -858993460:858993460
 TIME-OUT                -858933460:-858993460

 PARKING TIME             0:-858993460

 TOTAL CHARGE             -214748352.00
```

And here is my code

```
 #include <iostream>   //used for cout/cin
 #include <iomanip>   //used to manipulate data 


 void getData(int* ehour, int* emin, int* exhour, int* exmin);
 void rate(int exhour, int exmin, int ehour, int emin, int* thour, int* tmin, int* round);
 void charge(char* vehic, float* rate1, float* rate2, int ehour);
 void result(int exhour, int exmin, int ehour, int emin, int thour, float rate1, float rate2, int round, float total);

 int main(void)
 {
   char vehic;
   int ehour;
   int emin;
   int exhour;
   int exmin;
   int thour;
   int tmin;
   int round;

   float rate1;
   float rate2;
   float total;

   getData(&ehour, &emin, &exhour, &exmin);
   rate(exhour, exmin, ehour, emin, &thour, &tmin, &round);
   charge(&vehic, &rate1, &rate2, ehour);
   total= rate1 + rate2;
   result( exhour, exmin, ehour, emin, thour, rate1, rate2, round, total);
   return 0;
 }

  void getData(int* ehour, int* emin, int* exhour, int* exmin)
 {
   char v;
   printf("Enter C for car, B for bus, T for truck: ");
   scanf("%c", &v);
   printf("\nHour vehicle entered 0-24: ");
   scanf("%d", &ehour);
   printf("\nMinute vehicle entered 0-60: ");
   scanf("%d", &emin);
   printf("\nHour vehicle exited 0-24: ");
   scanf("%d", &exhour);
   printf("\nMinute vehicle exited 0-60: ");
   scanf("%d", &exmin);
   return;
 }
 void rate(int exhour, int exmin, int ehour, int emin, int* thour, int* tmin, int* round)
 {
   if(emin < exmin)
   {
          emin= emin + 60;
          exhour= exhour - 1;
   }
   *thour = ehour - exhour;
   *tmin = emin - exmin;
   if ((*tmin > 0 && *tmin <= 60))
   {
          *thour = *thour + 1;
          *round = *tmin * 0;
   }
   return;
 }
 void charge(char* vehic, float* rate1, float* rate2, int ehour)
 {
   switch (*vehic)
   {
   case 'c': if (ehour <= 3)
                   {
                         *rate1 = 0.00;
                         if (ehour > 3)
                              *rate2 = 1.25 * (ehour - 3);
                   }
                   break;

   case 'b': if (ehour <= 2)
                   {
                         *rate1 = 2.00 * ehour;
                         if (ehour > 2)
                                *rate2 = 2.50 * (ehour - 2);
                   }
                   break;
   case 't': if (ehour <= 1)
                   {
                         *rate1 = 3.75 * ehour;
                         if (ehour > 1)
                         *rate2 = 4.50 * (ehour - 1);
                   }
                   break;
   }
   return;
 }
 void result(int exhour, int exmin, int ehour, int emin, int thour, float rate1, float rate2, int round, float total)
 {
   printf("\n\t\t PARKING LOT CHARGE \t\t\n");
   printf("\nType of vehicle: Car or Bus or Truck");
   printf("\nTIME-IN\t\t %d:%d", ehour, emin);
   printf("\nTIME-OUT\t\t %d:%d", exhour, exmin);
   printf("\n\t\t\t --------");
   printf("\nPARKING TIME\t\t %d:%d", thour, round);
   printf("\n\t\t\t --------");
   total= rate1 + rate2;
   printf("\nTOTAL CHARGE\t\t %4.2f\n\n", total);

   return;
   }
```

I am sorry this is alot of code! I am just so puzzled!!! Are my ints not formatted correctly? Is the math wrong?

Comment: Can you post the error(s) you're getting?

Comment: There is no error. When I run the program, the first block of code is the result. My Total Charge should only be a few bucks and not -214748352.00 lol

Comment: Why are you using `scanf` and pointers? If this is really supposed to be C++, start from scratch. This can be done in a few lines.

Comment: Well, yes, but if use pointers, use pointers and not pointers to pointers.

Comment: You aren't having trouble with either integers or math, you're having trouble with pointers. It's a very common problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char v;
printf("Enter C for car, B for bus, T for truck: ");
scanf("%c", &v);
printf("\nHour vehicle entered 0-24: ");
scanf("%d", ehour);
printf("\nMinute vehicle entered 0-60: ");
scanf("%d", emin);
printf("\nHour vehicle exited 0-24: ");
scanf("%d", exhour);
printf("\nMinute vehicle exited 0-60: ");
scanf("%d", exmin);
```

You took the address of the parameters, which were *already pointers*.

---

As a general finger exercise, here's what you could do in more typical C++ style:

```
/////////////////////////////////////
// timepoint classes (booking.hpp)

struct timepoint
{
    int hour, minute;

    timepoint normalized()                     const; 
    int totalMinutes    ()                     const; 
    int roundedHours    ()                     const; 
    timepoint operator- (timepoint const& rhs) const; 
};

struct booking_t
{
    char vehicle;
    timepoint enter, exit;

    timepoint parked() const { return exit - enter; }
};

/////////////////////////////////////
// main program (main.cpp)
booking_t inputData();
void displayBill(booking_t const& booking);

int main(void)
{
    auto booking = inputData();
    displayBill(booking);
}

/////////////////////////////////////
// timepoint methods (booking.cpp)

timepoint timepoint::normalized() const
{
    timepoint tmp { (hour + minute/60) % 24, minute % 60 };
    while (tmp.minute < 0) tmp.hour--, tmp.minute+=60;
    while (tmp.hour   < 0) tmp.hour+=24;
    return tmp;
}

int timepoint::roundedHours() const
{
    return (totalMinutes()-1) / 60 + 1; // TODO check rounding logic
}

int timepoint::totalMinutes() const
{
    return hour*60 + minute;
}

timepoint timepoint::operator-(timepoint const& rhs) const
{
    return timepoint { 0, totalMinutes() - rhs.totalMinutes() } .normalized();
}

#include <iostream>   //used for cout/cin

timepoint getTime(std::string label)
{
    int hour, minute;
    std::cout  << "\nHour "   << label << " 0-24: ";
    std::cin >> hour;
    std::cout  << "\nMinute " << label << " 0-60: ";
    std::cin >> minute;
    return { hour, minute };
}

/////////////////////////////////////
// global functions - input
booking_t inputData()
{
    std::cout << "Enter C for car, B for bus, T for truck: ";
    char v;
    std::cin >> v;
    auto entered = getTime("vehicle entered");
    auto exited  = getTime("vehicle exited");
    return { v, entered.normalized(), exited.normalized() };
}

/////////////////////////////////////
// calculation + billing
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>   //used to manipulate data 
#include <map>

static std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, timepoint const& tp)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << tp.hour << ':' 
        << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << tp.minute;
    return os << oss.str();
}

std::pair<float,float> charge(booking_t const& booking)
{
    struct tariff_t { int threshold; float rate1, rate2; };
    const static auto tariffs = std::map<char, tariff_t> {
        { 'c', { 3, 0   , 1.25 } },
        { 'b', { 2, 2.  , 2.5  } },
        { 't', { 1, 3.75, 4.5 } } ,
    };

    auto& tariff = tariffs.at(std::tolower(booking.vehicle));
    auto  parked = booking.parked().roundedHours();

    return std::make_pair(
            tariff.rate1 * std::min(tariff.threshold, parked)    ,
            tariff.rate2 * std::max(0, parked - tariff.threshold));
}

void displayBill(booking_t const& booking)
{
    std::cout << "\n\n    PARKING LOT CHARGE\n";
    std::cout << "Type of vehicle: Car or Bus or Truck\n";
    std::cout << "TIME-IN         " << booking.enter << "\n";
    std::cout << "TIME-OUT        " << booking.exit  << "\n";
    std::cout << "                " << "--------\n";
    std::cout << "PARKING TIME    " << booking.parked() << "\n";
    std::cout << "        ROUNDED " << booking.parked().roundedHours() << "\n";
    std::cout << "                " << "--------\n";

    auto  rates = charge(booking);
    float total = rates.first + rates.second;
    std::cout << "TOTAL CHARGE    " << std::fixed << std::setw(7) << std::setprecision(2) << total << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain a little more since Im a beginner? Would that mean to change scanf("%c") to scanf("c")? And so on?

Comment: No, look at what sehe posted, look at your code. See the difference. He's told you exactly what to do.

Comment: @Rockies for fun and giggles, I have added a C++ implementation in C++ style: **[http://ideone.com/urdLP2](http://ideone.com/urdLP2)** I've made some assumptions about what you probably _intended_ sometimes (the charge function had useless nested conditionals). Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I can't find much redeeming about your original code, so this isn't an answer per se, but perhaps you might find it interesting how I would write code for your problem in "pure C++":

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

bool parse_time(std::string const & s, int & t)
{
    int h, m;
    char c;

    std::istringstream iss(s);

    if (iss >> h >> c >> m >> std::ws && c == ':' && iss.get() == EOF)
    {
        t = 60 * h + m;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int t_in, t_out;
    std::string line;

    if (!(std::cout << "Enter arrival time: "   &&
          std::getline(std::cin, line)          &&
          parse_time(line, t_in)                &&
          std::cout << "Enter departure time: " &&
          std::getline(std::cin, line)          &&
          parse_time(line, t_out)))
    {
        std::cerr << "Input error! Aborting.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "You spent " << t_out - t_in << " minutes.\n";
}
```

Here's a typical session:

```
Enter arrival time: 5:14
Enter departure time: 8:41
You spent 207 minutes.
```

Comment: lol. Your version is shorter; Cf. [my version](http://ideone.com/urdLP2). I included the tarriff structure and bill printing, though :). +1 Cheers

Comment: @sehe: Hehe, yours looks nice, though, and is probably a better example of doing things in a structured way. Though I see a naked `std::cin >> v` in your code, without checking the return value!

Comment: leaving something to the OP :) Arguably, the fact that the calculations weren't working, and times across midnight weren't being handled makes up for a bit of that, I suppose.

Comment: @sehe: Yeah, sure, but I'm confident that the OP would never work out in a million years that the input logic breaks when facing anything but the exactly expected input... Hundreds of SO questions have made me convinced me of that.

Comment: I don't doubt it for a second. I also know that the OP is not going to learn everything at once. Just putting it out there. Mainly for my own enjoyment. Always exercising the elementals

Answer (score 1):

One thing I noticed — You pass `&ehour` and friends, which is a pointer to pointer to your `scanf` call (you can start by removing `&` from `scanf` calls when `ehour` is `int*`).

Answer (score 1):

Take out the & in scanf! They are already pointers!

Answer (score 1):

The other error in your code is that the variable `vehic` never gets a value. It looks like you meant to give it a value in `getData` but messed that up somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Rule 1: Declare variables near to where you first use them.  And initialize all variables when you create them:

```
int main(void)
{
  int ehour = 0;
  int emin = 0;
  int exhour = 0;
  int exmin = 0;
  getData(&ehour, &emin, &exhour, &exmin);

  int thour = 0;
  int tmin = 0;
  int round = 0;
  rate(exhour, exmin, ehour, emin, &thour, &tmin, &round);

  char vehic = 0;
  float rate1 = 0;
  float rate2 = 0;
  charge(&vehic, &rate1, &rate2, ehour);

  float total = 0;
  total= rate1 + rate2;
  result( exhour, exmin, ehour, emin, thour, rate1, rate2, round, total);
  return 0;
}
```

Now see that `float total`?  Move the declaration and initialization of the variable to the same line:

```
  float total = rate1 + rate2;
```

Rule 2: Don't use pointers if you don't need to.  If you have an integer you want to pass both into and out of a function, make the parameter a reference parameter like this:

```
 void getData(int& ehour, int& emin, int& exhour, int& exmin)
```

In main:

```
  getData(ehour, emin, exhour, exmin);
```

In getData:

```
void getData(int& ehour, int& emin, int& exhour, int& exmin)
{
  char v;
  printf("Enter C for car, B for bus, T for truck: ");
  scanf("%c", &v);
  printf("\nHour vehicle entered 0-24: ");
  scanf("%d", &ehour);
  printf("\nMinute vehicle entered 0-60: ");
  scanf("%d", &emin);
  printf("\nHour vehicle exited 0-24: ");
  scanf("%d", &exhour);
  printf("\nMinute vehicle exited 0-60: ");
  scanf("%d", &exmin);
  return;
}
```

Now, I spotted your first screwup.  You where reading not to the integers, but to the pointers to the integers.  Now that I have made them references (think "aliases" or for the variables passed in), the `&` operator gets a pointer to the integer, not a pointer to the pointer to the integer!

The next thing you want to do is not to use scanf.  Scanf is hard to use.  Why use something hard to use?

Step 3: Your program should help you debug it.

When you read something from input, repeat it back out to make sure you read it right.  Ie, after you call getData, the very next thing you should do is repeat out what you read.  Eventually when your code is solid you can remove that "repeat it back", but when developing a program this kind of feedback is essential.

See Kerrek SB for better ways to read instead of using `scanf`.